# position:absolute and fill remaining space in div

Tags: css, html

Please have a look at the following configuration:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJYLpe?editors=110

I would like my `#right` div to stay at the right of the screen with a pre-defined width and I would like my `#left` div to fill the remaining space. Note that the `#imagetag` needs to stay at the bottom right of the filler div without needing a manual positioning.

**Please know that this is not a duplicate** - all of the provided solutions here require the "filler" div to have no position property - however I need the `position:absolute` property to make `overflow:hidden` work properly for my case (as you can see contained image is bigger than the container - it needs to be hidden)

Open to suggestions.

Comment: It is actually a duplicate. But not closing it for now. Have a look at my answer. `:)`

Comment: Is this what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqvvV?editors=110

Comment: @PraveenKumar no, please notice the change in image behavior

Comment: Nothing happened. It is in the same position. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PraveenKumar if you check my original example image is bigger than the div that carries it. Therefore it's cropped by overflow:hidden

Comment: @PraveenKumar moreover I just realized you input the image-tag distance manually. it should auto position itself with the content

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

on the `#right` and then use `calc(100% - 200px)` on `#left`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXRdPv?editors=110

Comment: This, too, changes the image. Please check the actual link - the image is cropped and bigger than the div.

Comment: @Mia use `background-size: contain` on the `div` to resolve that oversizing of the HD bg image.

Comment: i want the oversizing

Answer (score 0):

**Edit from a previous answer, so comments might not be up to date.**

Changes:

```
#left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#right {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

And moved the image tag to be a container for the "left" and "right" boxes

**See Fiddle:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqVzNY?editors=110

Comment: this does not work as you can see -- the imagetag div stays behind.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort - however making the image 100% width and height changes how it behaves. I need the image to be bigger, and overflow:hidden to display a portion of it (as in the original example)

Comment: Last final go :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pqvevp?editors=110 .. After that I'm out of ideas, sorry.. Oh, it was already mentioned below.. Then I'm dry

Comment: How about this @Mia ? Did this solve your question? I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use positioning for this case. This is a case of:

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Fixed-Fluid Model. In my snippet, I have demonstrated two kinds of examples. In the first case, the fluid is less in size. And the next has too long content.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {background-color: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque animi placeat, expedita tempora explicabo facilis nulla fuga recusandae officia, maiores porro eaque, dolore et modi in sapiente accusamus id aut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate this on my example? The image problem I explained above does not allow this to work the same way.

Comment: I am - I replied to you above - please notice the change in image behavor -- this is not what I'm looking for. Image needs to stay cropped (by the overflow)

Comment: Exactly @Mia, Nothing happened. It **is** in the same position. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what browsers you want to support but my go for this would be flexbox

**Browser support of flexbox** http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

In flexbox you can set a **min** and **max** width to a div and next to it it will be responsive

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqVzpz?editors=110

set the carry to flex

```
#carry {
   display: flex; 
};
```

and the left to flex and only adding a width to the right one

```
#left {
  flex: 1;
}
#right {
  background-color: pink;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px; 
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

if you wane know what more awesome stuff flexbox is capable of check this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: THank you, I'm looking for a no-flex solution

Answer (score -1):

Add `float: right` on your `#right` element and add `float: left` on your `#left` element.

Also, the  width of `#left` and `#right` elements should share a total of 100%.

Set the width and height to 100% on the `#image` element. Then apply the size of the image on `background-size: 130%`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqVMOv?editors=110

Comment: This does not solve the problem - the width does not "fill" -- the "#imagetag" stays behind

Comment: This is actually not a solution at all. What is even going on in the link? it's not even getting the true width for the right element - useless suggestion.

Comment: Many things - starting from: the div does not auto scale, there is 90% you entered manually

Comment: @Mia, you want #left and #right to share a total of 100% width because they are the child of #carry. The #image is a child of #left , its acting as a background, scaling the image should be done on the background-size not the width and height; this way it allows it remain responsive.  You need to be clear with what you're trying to achieve.